# rails 2 replace_html puts javascript into the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototypejs, rjs

In my controller I have:

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
```

In my rjs:

```
page.replace_html("source_credential_list", :partial => "source_credential_list", :object => @all_source_credentials)
```

or

```
page.replace("source_credential_list", :partial => "source_credential_list", :object => @all_source_credentials)
```

In my partial: (

```
<% fields_for(@brand_report_source_credential_key) do |ff|  %>
   <%= ff.select :source_credential_id , options_from_collection_for_select(@all_source_credentials,'id','credential_display_name')%>
<% end %>
```

In my orig view:

```
  <span id="source_credential_list">
    <%= render :partial => 'source_credential_list' %>
  </span>
```

When I do replace it works great, but only one time, the 2nd time I get a alert with a null, I suspect because the span is gone. If I do replace_html, it kinda works, it updates the span but it puts the actual rjs/javascript into the span including the new select/drop down. So something like this:

Source credential
try { Element.update("source_credential_list", "\n \n\n"); } catch (e) { alert('RJS error:\n\n' + e.toString()); alert('Element.update(\"source_credential_list\", \"\n \n\n\");'); throw e }

I tried moving the span into the partial and doing both combos, but nothing working. Im sure its something obvious....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what piece of code is triggering this action, but assuming it's triggered by a link_to_remote call, make sure you don't have an :update => "source_credential_list" parameter in your link_to_remote call -- otherwise it will both execute the RJS and update the element specified with the javascript code.

See here: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?pid=44191#p44191

Also, when you do page.replace, it only works once because page.replace replaces the specified element, **including** the surrounding tags, so unless the partial you specify includes the span tag, it'll disappear the first time it's used.

Comment: awesome, you are right, it was an onchange => remote_function, but it did have an update clause in it also.